# IIS hosted web application works fine with ssl without www, gives 404 error with www

Tags: ssl, web, redirect, iis, http-status-code-404

Good morning.
I have a web application (made with angular if useful) hosted with IIS on a windows server 2016 with certificate (made with Let's Encrypts wacs) that works fine with ssl.
the problem is, if i use www the site not only appear as not safe, but also gives 404 error.
I tried the following rule on web.config to redirect to non www but without success

```
<rule name="Redirect WWW to non-WWW" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

I have other rules, thats my complete webconfig file: https://pastebin.com/wRWarfCV

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Clear the cache and try again. Can you show me which url did you want to redirect? please check if the parameter `^example\.com$` matches your url, If it still doesn't work, you can only use failed request tracking to get detailed error information

Comment: @samwu i checked the pattern and it is correct. i'm trying to redirect all request starting with www to request without the www. for example, i'm trying to redirect https://www.example.com (that gives me error 404 and unsafe certificate) to https://example.com

Answer (score 0):

I think https://www.example.com and https://example.com are Different domains. you need to reissue certificate and add http://example.com as primary domain and add other domain http://www.example.com.

More information you can refer to this link: [How do I reissue my SSL certificate?](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/811/70/how-do-i-reissue-my-ssl-certificate/).